# Is the Islamic prophet Muhammad mentioned in the Bible? If so, where is it?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, bible

I have heard from several pious and sincere Muslims I met in my travels who claimed that the Islamic Prophet Muhammad has been prophesied in the Bible. But, unfortunately they could not show me any clear evidence in the Bible. Being a follower of Jesus Christ I have read the Bible several times. However, I have never found once in the Bible about the coming of a prophet called Muhammad. Sometimes I wonder if it is a mere claim or a claim with evidence.

Comment: I have a blog post that perhaps answers your question: https://veiledink.wordpress.com/2016/10/15/mentionsreferences-of-prophet-muhammad-%ef%b7%ba-in-the-bible/ Easier to just read it there than to c/p here.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into that as time permits me and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

From [Mentions/References of Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ) in the Bible](https://veiledink.wordpress.com/2016/10/15/mentionsreferences-of-prophet-muhammad-%EF%B7%BA-in-the-bible/)

Today when we go through the Bible, we find that numerous references to him have survived. Below is a compilation of many of the references pointed out by Dai’ees (callers to Islam) from people such as Ahmad Deedat to Zakir Naik to Dr. Laurence Brown and many others. May Allah (ﷻ) reward them all.

① The most significant verse from the Bible is that in which the beloved Prophet’s name, Muhammad is mentioned. In Song of Solomon 5:16 the original text reads: חכו ממתקים וכלו מחמדים זה דודי וזה רעי בנות ירושלם. The original Hebrew word in the verse mentioning the name Muhammad is “מחמד”. [These letters in English are MHMD and in Arabic are محمد (Muhammad)].

② The same chapter of Song of Solomon (5:10-16) also gives descriptions that describe him accurately.. such as white/ruddy and Arabic appearance. Status-wise, it mentions the person is “the chiefest among ten thousand.” (The Bible mentions thousands coming to judge and order by God’s command). Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ) was the leader of 10,000 men. From hadith: “The Prophet (ﷺ) left Medina (for Mecca) in the company of ten-thousand (Muslim warriors) in (the month of) Ramadan, and that was eight and a half years after his migration to Medina” ~ Bukhari (4276).

③ Another reference touches upon the illiteracy of the Prophet (ﷺ). The Bible records [a prophecy of what “will” happen]: “Then the book will be given to the one who is illiterate, saying, “Please read this.” And he will say, “I cannot read.” ” Isaiah 29:12. This is what happened hundreds of years later, when Angel Jibrail (Gabriel) approached Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ) with the Qur’an. From hadith: “The angel came to him and asked him to read. The Prophet (ﷺ) replied, ‘I do not know how to read'” – Bukhari (3).

④ Per the Qur’an, Prophet ‘Isa (‘Jesus’) gave glad tidings of a Prophet to come. He said he comes with “good tidings of a messenger to come after me, whose name is Ahmad” (61:6). Per the Bible, Jesus said: “when he, the Spirit of truth, comes, he will guide you into all the truth. He will not speak on his own; he will speak only what he hears, and he will tell you what is yet to come” -John 16:13. Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ) had the titles, “Al- Sadiq Al-Amin” (the Truthful, the Trustworthy) and Allah (ﷻ) said the Prophet doesn’t speak of his own desires. “Nor does he speak from [his own] inclination. It is not but a revelation revealed” – Qur’an 53:3-4.

⑤ [Another Prophet expected]: The Bible mentions John the Baptist being asked who he is. He “openly declared, “I am not the Christ”. They asked him, “Then who are you? Are you Elijah?” He said, “I am not.” “Are you the Prophet?” He answered, “No.” – John 1:20-21. The verse rules out that “the Prophet” is either Jesus or Elijah or John the Baptist himself. So who is “the Prophet”? — Obviously the foretold and expected Prophet, Muhammad (ﷺ).

This is a short list of numerous more references.